# Find the unique element of length 1 in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to run the function glmnet(), but i get the following error:

> Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,
>   :    one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not
>   allowed.

I already removed all factors which have zero observations. I did this using

```
data<- data %>% droplevels()
```

For glmnet() I used 83 variables, so I would not like to check all variables whether they contain a factor of 1 observation. How could I easily check which variables/columns have a factor of 1 observation? Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a sample data?

Comment: No sorry, I can't share this data. I could create some data if it makes it more clear? But my question is quite general: How can I find from all factor columns the names of the columns with only one element of a certain factor. Like for example, you could use table(data[,1]) and find 4 observations for 1, 2 observations for 2 and 1 observation for 3. Then I would like to retrieve column 1 since this column has an 'unique' factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
too_few_obs = function(a_factor) {
  any(table(a_factor)<=1)
}

colwise(too_few_obs)(data)
```